# Asignacion de variables dentro de funcion

Tags: python, funciones, variables

Tengo esta duda y no se si es un error o solo una advertencia. Tengo esta función muy simple la cual dependiendo del valor ingresado arroja un mensaje alojado dentro de la variable opción, cuando llamo a la función y le paso el valor del parámetro funciona correctamente pero  el `return` me figura marcado de color amarillo, ¿estoy haciendo algo mal? o ¿todo va ok?

```
def opcion1(carga):
  if carga == "automatica" or carga == "Automatica":
    opcion = "Usted eligio carga automatica"

  else:
    if carga == "manual" or carga == "Manual":
      opcion = "Usted eligio carga manual"

  return opcion


print(opcion1("Automatica"))
```

Cuando posiciono el ratón sobre el error figura:

> Local variable "opcion" might be referenced before assignment...

Comment: Debes colocar el código como texto.

Comment: Listo, perdon :)

Comment: ¿Y que pasa si no se entra en ningún condicional? En ese caso `opción` no será definida... ¿Si ninguno de los condicionales se cumpliera que debería retornar la función? Es decir, ¿si carga no es "automatica", "Automatica", "manual" o "Manual"  que debería pasar?

Comment: declara la variable opcion  al inicio de la funcion

Comment: Dentro del else coloque otro else debajo del if y el error desaparecio, por otro lado @JackNavaRow a que te refieres con declarar la variable al comienzo de la función, seria igual a que ?

Comment: lo que queremos decir es que declarala al inicio de la funcion , puede que no entre a ningun if y la variable no este declarada nunca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero aclarar que **no es una excepción lanzada por el intérprete, es solo una advertencia del analizador de código del IDE** que nos avisa que se puede dar la situación en la que la variable `opcion` no esté definida y por tanto, ocasionar una excepción en tiempo de ejecución:

- Si la función recibe "Automatica", "automatica", "Manual" o "manual":

  ```
  >>> print(opcion1("Automatica"))
  "Usted eligio carga automatica"
  ```

  Nada ocurre, la función retorna correctamente porque se cumple el primer condicional y se define opción  `opcion = "Usted eligio carga automatica"`.
- Si la función recibe cualquier cosa que no sea las cuatro cadenas anteriores:

  ```
  >>> print(opcion1("AUTOMATICA"))
  ```

  Tenemos el problema sobre el que el IDE nos avisaba:

  > Exception has occurred: UnboundLocalError
  >       local variable 'opcion' referenced before assignment

  Esto ocurre porque no se cumple ningún condicional y dado que `opcion` solo se define dentro de los dos condicionales,queda sin definir, por lo que en `return opción` la variable no existe.

Aún planteándote que que tu función solo va a recibir valores válidos, no debes dar nunca pie a que esta situación pueda ocurrir. `opcion` debe ser definida antes de llegar al `return` o impedir que se llegue al `return` si no va a estar definida.

Las soluciones son muchas, pero primero dos apuntes:

- Tu `else` con el `if` dentro no tiene sentido, usa un `elif` simplemente.
- Puedes (si no es una tarea y no te dejan) usar `str.lower()` para pasar la cadena recibida a minúscula, lo cual facilita la comparación.

Dicho esto tienes muchas opciones para resolver la situación, entre ellas:

- Puedes plantearte definir la variable con un valor por defecto si no se entra en ningún condicional, tal como comenta @JackNavaRow:

  ```
  def opcion1(carga):
      opcion = "Usted no ha elegido una opcion valida"
      carga = carga.lower()
      if carga == "automatica":
          opcion = "Usted eligio carga automatica"
      elif carga == "manual":
          opcion = "Usted eligio carga manual"
      return opcion
  ```
- También puedes usar una construcción `if-elif-else`:

  ```
  def opcion1(carga):
      carga = carga.lower()
      if carga == "automatica":
          opcion = "Usted eligio carga automatica"
      elif carga == "manual":
          opcion = "Usted eligio carga manual"
      else:
          carga = "Usted no ha elegido una opcion valida"
      return opcion
  ```
- Prescindir de la variable y usar múltiples `return`:

  ```
  def opcion1(carga):
      carga = carga.lower()
      if carga == "automatica":
          return "Usted eligio carga automatica"
      elif carga == "manual":
          return "Usted eligio carga manual"
      else:
          return "Usted no ha elegido una opcion valida"
  ```
- Otra opción, aunque creo que no se ajusta al uso que le das a tu función, sería lanzar una excepción adecuada (`ValueError`) si el valor del argumento no se ajusta a lo esperado:

  ```
  def opcion1(carga):
      carga = carga.lower()
      if carga == "automatica":
          return "Usted eligio carga automatica"
      elif carga == "manual":
          return "Usted eligio carga manual"
      else:
          raise ValueError("El argumento carga debe ser 'automatica' o 'manual'")
  ```

Comment: excelente explicación, me sacaste todas las dudas, gracias compañero.

Answer (score 1):

Saludos te sugiero realizar de la siguiente manera:

```
def opcion1(carga):
  if carga.lower() == "automatica":
    opcion = "Usted eligio carga automatica"
  elif carga.lower() == "manual":
    opcion = "Usted eligio carga manual"
  else:
    opcion = "Error, elija Manual/Automatica"
  return opcion

print(opcion1("Automatic"))
```

**Explicación**

Basicamente lo que hace es primero convertir la opción a minusculas con **.lower()**
luego mediante un **if** valido si es alguna de estas opciones deseadas, caso contrario deberias regresar un mensaje de error o lo que desees hacer segun la logica respectiva.

Con esto podras obtener algo asi:
[image: result]

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Gracias por la explicacion @Diego Avila, fue de mucha ayuda